# Take ownership of a file in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I am currently following the steps presented in this [tutorial](http://danielcai.blogspot.co.nz/2012/05/install-crm-2011-on-windows-server-8.html). At step 3 I am supposed to take ownership over the file `svrmgrnc.dll` in ´System32´. I am in Administrators group but in the security tab the button to edit those settings is disabled. TrustedInstaller is currently holding full control over the file. Usually I would expect that Administrators could take over every file. 
Additional info: It is a Domain Controller!

Comment: Why are you trying to follow a tutorial when the first line tells you that you don't need it any more because the vendor released a solution ?

Comment: Did you try that from an elevated process ?

Comment: The vendor does not support a direct installation on Windows Server 2012. The only way is to install on a 2008 R2, apply RU13 und then upgrade the complete Server to 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up an elevated command prompt, then: `takeown /f "C:\windows\System32\svrmgrnc.dll"`